# Keychain Not Working - Inside Pod Tests

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I building a pod that utilizes the keychain (using `KeychainSwift`). However, I am having difficulty setting values to the keychain when running tests. The OSStatus code that I get from Keychain is -50.

Are there any issues that I should be aware of when using the Keychain across targets or as a dependency for a pod?

Answer (score 1):

-50 (often) means wrong argument, so my first guess would be that one of the APIs is calling with invalid/lacking parameters.